# Maven Jboss plugin configuration for a multi-module project having a child module as WAR

Tags: maven, jboss

I am working on a maven multi-module project having the following folder structure.

```
+---parent_module
    +---module1
    +---module2
    +---module_web
```

How do I configure 'jboss-as-maven-plugin' for a local and remote deploy? Note that I want to deploy the child module_web which is the WAR residing inside the parent_module. I ran command 'mvn clean install' and the build completed successfully and the module_web.war file was created.

Then I ran the mvn command 'mvn -e -X package jboss-as:deploy' from parent_module to deploy the WAR to the jboss container, I get the following error.

> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.4.Final:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project markodojo: Could not execute goal deploy on
>   C:\Mahesh\Git\markodojo\markodojo\target\markodojo_solution-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war.
>   Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{ [ERROR] "address" =>
>   [], [ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute", [ERROR] "name" =>
>   "launch-type" [ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could
>   not connect to remote://localhost:8080. The connection timed out
>   [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Below are the snippets from the pom.xml files.

**Parent module pom.xml**

```
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module_web</module>
  </modules>

  <properties>
  .....
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
  .....
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.1</version>
          <configuration>
             <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
             <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>

       <!-- JBoss AS plugin to deploy war -->
       <!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.4.Final</version>
          <!-- inherited>true</inherited-->
          <configuration>
             <jbossHome>C:\folderpath\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final</jbossHome>
             <serverName>standalone</serverName>
             <hostname>localhost</hostname>
             <port>8080</port>
             <filename>module_web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war</filename>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        other plugins...
    <plugins>
</build>
```

**module1 pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>module1</name>
```

**module2 pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>module2</name>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     other dependencies ...
  </dependencies>
```

**module_web pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>module_web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>module_web</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     other dependencies ...
  </dependencies>
```

Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong with the plugin configuration? It would be of great help if you share any tutorial or maven-jboss document which explains the steps to configure the maven-jboss plugin for a multi-module project having a child module as WAR.

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it with reference to this JBoss community https://community.jboss.org/thread/212123?start=0&tstart=0

I defined the 'jboss-as-maven-plugin in parent POM and disabled it using the command '<skip>true</skip>` and overridden the plugin by defining in the child POM which is my WAR module. Also one more change: I removed the port setting and hence it uses the default port. Now on executing the `mvn clean package jboss-as:deploy`, the child module WAR is packed and deployed to the local JBoss container.